# How can I force wireshark to decipher some types of protocols if it doesn't recognize them (RTSP,RTP, RTCP)?

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, rtsp, rtp

I'm  trying to implement RTSP protocol in Java according to http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html example; I have succeed up to successful communication with VLC via RTSP requests and streaming RTP packets; RTP packets with JPEG payload are not recognized by VLC well; that's why I supposed I send malformed RTP. I sniffed them with wireshark and compared them with packets, sniffed from successfull RTSP communication of gstreamer RTSP streamer and VLc. I was surprised, that both my app&VLC's RTSP and RTP requests were labeled in wireshark UI as simply TCP and UDP packets, while gstreamer&VLC's one were labeled as RTSP, RTP, RTCP, and even RTSP/SDP.

I'm really confused, I don't understand why VLC's requsts in some cases are parsed by wireshark as pure RTSP/RTP, and im my case as plain TCP/UDP data. At least, VLC's requests are not malformed, even if my are.

How can I force wireshark to recognize that requests as some specific protocol?

Comment: So I'm guessing gstreamer/VLC are sending the SDP session initiation and that you are not?

Comment: Actually, I'm sending, but I'm not sure that it is not malformed. At least it had been never deciphered as SDP out-of-the-box (as well as other RTSP requests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on a packet and select "Decode as...". Then choose "RTP" in the list of "Transport" protocols.

If you want to decode some custom-made protocol, you'll have to get or compile a dissector, which can be quite troublesome... Fortunately, PCAP format is simple and plugin directly to it is easy (I happened to just have made one last week, I might make it Open Source if my boss agrees).

Thanks to @GuyHarris who stated that automatic RTP decoding is performed when SDP packets are detected that initiate the RTP session. There also is an option in the "*Edit > Preferences*" menu, choosing "*RTP*" under the "*Protocols*" tree: "*Try to decode RTP outside of conversations*".

Comment: Thank you! I tried and now I see all headers as they were encoded. Now the questions is why it doesn't do it out-of-the-box for my packets (and VLC requests to my app) and do for gstreamer-VLC communication...

Comment: I don't know. I never saw Wireshark do automatic RTP recognition on the devices I work with. And I don't see anything in a raw packet that tells it *is* RTP. Maybe according to different types of payload? (see RFC3551 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3551).

Comment: After a little search, it turns out it will decode automatically when there is a valid SDP header in the packet (http://wiki.wireshark.org/SDP)

Comment: "decode automatically when there is a valid SDP header in the packet" Or, rather, when there's are SDP packets earlier in the capture setting up an RTP session.  There's also an RTP preference "Try to decode RTP outside conversations" (and a corresponding RTCP preference) to make Wireshark try to heuristically determine whether a packet is RTP (RTCP).

Comment: Thanks @GuyHarris, I'll update my answer to include your comment.

Comment: Thank you guys for detailed explanation! May be you can explain me the roots of some other, but similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968923/how-can-i-decode-rtp-packet-of-some-specific-rtp-payload-type-as-rtp-packet-with